# Как изменить знак каждого локального минимума в бинарном файле

Tags: java

Есть *.bin* файл, содержащий массив чисел:

```
new int[] { 12, 6, 7, -1, 5, 15, 6, 4, -1, 15, 5 }
```

Есть метод, который в цикле ищет локальный минимум и меняет его знак на противоположный:

```
private static void doWork() {
    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw")) {
        int n = (int)raf.length() / Integer.BYTES; // Кол-во
        int prevValue = raf.readInt(); // пред. элемент.
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            // текущий элемент.
            int value = raf.readInt();
            // позиция текущего элемента
            long pos = raf.getFilePointer();
            // следующий элемент.
            int nextValue = raf.readInt();
            if (value < prevValue && value < nextValue) {
                raf.seek(pos);
                raf.writeInt(-value);
            }
        } // for i
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} // doWork
```

Но он не работает должным образом: меняет только один раз знак на противоположный, да и то с пред. числом до локального минимума.

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: это три числа `6`,`-1`,`-1`. Локальный минимум - это там где производная меняет знак с минуса на плюс.

Comment: Alakay, внимательно посмотрите на состояние ваших переменных на второй итерации.

Comment: Локальный минимум - число,у которого оба соседа - слева и справа по значению больше числа по центру.

Comment: Кстати, а вот в ситуации `6,-1,-1,2` что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Значение `prevValue` не обновляется
2. В `pos` хранится позиция следующего элемента, а не текущего
3. Запуск кода приводит к `EOFException` из-за того, что в каждой итерации сдвиг по файлу происходит на 8 байтов, а не на 4.

Чтобы исправить проблемы из пунктов 2 и 3, нужно учитывать, что каждый вызов метода `readInt` приводит к смещению на 4 байта.

В итоге исправленный код получается такой:

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "test.txt";

private static void doWork()
{
    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(FILE_NAME, "rw"))
    {
        int n = (int)raf.length() / Integer.BYTES; // Кол-во
        int prevValue = raf.readInt(); // пред. элемент.
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            // позиция текущего элемента
            long pos = raf.getFilePointer(); //исправление пункта 2
            // текущий элемент.
            int value = raf.readInt();
            // следующий элемент.
            int nextValue = raf.readInt();
            if (value < prevValue && value < nextValue)
            {
                raf.seek(pos);
                raf.writeInt(-value);
            }
            else //исправление пункта 3
            {
                raf.seek(pos + Integer.BYTES);
            }
            prevValue = value; //исправление пункта 1
        } // for i
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} // doWork
```

Однако можно и не считывать каждое число по два раза: считывать только `nextValue`, а `prevValue` и `value` брать из предыдущей итерации:

```
private static void doWork()
{
    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(FILE_NAME, "rw"))
    {
        int numbersCount = (int)raf.length() / Integer.BYTES;
        if (numbersCount < 3)
        {
            return;
        }
        int prevValue = raf.readInt();
        int value = raf.readInt();
        for (int i = 2; i < numbersCount; i++)
        {
            int nextValue = raf.readInt();
            if (value < prevValue && value < nextValue)
            {
                long savedPos = raf.getFilePointer();
                raf.seek(savedPos - 2 * Integer.BYTES);
                raf.writeInt(-value);
                raf.seek(savedPos);
            }
            prevValue = value;
            value = nextValue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная ошибка - ты не обновляешь значение `prevValue` на следующих итерациях.

Пример реализации без файлов:

```
public class Task
{
  private int[] numbers;
  public Task(int[] numbers){ this.numbers = numbers;}

  public void transform() {
    int prev = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
      int current = numbers[i];
      int next = numbers[i+1];
      if (current < next && current < prev) {
        numbers[i] = -numbers[i];
      }
      prev = current; // <-- Это важно
    }
  }
  public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
}
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] input = new int[]{ 12, 6, 7, -1, 5, 15, 6, 4, -1, 15, 5 };
    Task task = new Task(input);
    task.print();    // 12 6 7 -1 5 15 6 4 -1 15 5 
    task.transform();
    task.print();    // 12 -6 7 1 5 15 6 4 1 15 5 
    task.transform();
    task.print();    // 12 6 7 -1 5 15 6 4 -1 15 5
  }
}
```